# Getting ScreenRenderException while running OfBiz

Tags: java, eclipse, erp, ofbiz

I am new to OfBiz.while running it in eclipse...I got the following in eclipse console...

```
Httpd started on port: 9989
Sessiond started on port: 9990
2014-02-04 12:57:37,538 (main) [ BeanShellContainer.java:100:INFO ] Started BeanShell telnet service on 9989, 9990
2014-02-04 12:57:37,538 (main) [ BeanShellContainer.java:101:INFO ] NOTICE: BeanShell service ports are not secure. Please protect the ports
2014-02-04 12:57:45,824 (org.ofbiz.service.jms.JmsListenerFactory@6ec213ad) [ JmsListenerFactory.java:75 :INFO ] JMS Listener Factory Thread Finished; All listeners connected.
```

after this I am trying to open url `https://localhost:8080/webtools` as mentioned in the tutorial but i am experiencing the following error message in the browser

```
:ERROR MESSAGE:
org.ofbiz.widget.screen.ScreenRenderException: Error rendering screen [component://common/widget/CommonScreens.xml#GlobalDecorator]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Template location is empty (Template location is empty)
```

Help me to fix this...Thank You

Comment: Try `load-demo` and check the error log.

Comment: the readme says to run load-demo before ant start. So I guess the OP has already run this command. Or are you suggesting that he needs to run it again ?

Comment: I went into the exact issue. Running _ant load-demo_ from ofbiz root directory solved the problem!

Answer (score 3):

That error usually happens when you run the ant build without any additional command and then execute the application

> >ant

You can install the demo or a new installation, **to install the demo** run:

> >ant load-demo

**OR** to **install the new one** run:

> >ant run-install

if you need to **clean** before a new installation run:

> >ant clean-all

With the information and templates loaded the application should work now, run from eclipse or with the command

> startofbiz

Hope it helps

Regards